# Query to the database having a field in string

Tags: c#, linq

Can I somehow query the database for a field that I have in string?

```
string fieldName = "Column1";
```

SQL:

```
string sql = "SELECT " + fieldName + " FROM myTable";
```

I need to do this using `LINQ`

Is there something built-in and quick for such questions or does reflection come into play?

Comment: What would you want the Linq statement to look like?

Comment: Use a raw SQL Command?: `var values = context.Database.SqlQuery<dynamic>(sql).ToArray();`.

Comment: @mm8 I have error `'DatabaseFacade' does not contain a definition for 'ExecuteQuery' and no accessible extension method 'ExecuteQuery' accepting a first argument of type 'DatabaseFacade' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`. So it doesn't work

Comment: @startNet: You can't execute raw queries against a `DatabaseFacade` in a test.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a simple method for this:

```
private static IEnumerable<IDataRecord> ReadSqlRecords(string sql) {
  //TODO: Put connection string here
  //TODO: I've assumed you work with MS SQL; if not replace SqlConnection 
  using (var conn = new SqlConnection("ConnectionStringHere")) {
    conn.Open();

    using (var q = conn.CreateCommand()) {
      q.CommandText = sql;

      using (var reader = q.ExecuteReader()) {
        while (reader.Read())
          yield return reader;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can use it

```
string sql = $"SELECT {fieldName} FROM myTable";

// Now you can put Linq
var result = ReadSqlRecords(sql)     
  .Where(record => Convert.ToInt32(record["Id"]) > 100)
  .Count();
```

Comment: `var fieldName = "1; DROP TABLE myTable; --";`. I think it worth to add note to your answer, that SQL injection is possible here

Comment: @Aleks Andreev: sql injection is when *user* can inject *his/her own sql*, typical antipattern is `string sql = $"select {Edit1.Text} from MyTable";`; 
in this case `Edit1.Text` can well contain `123 from MyTable; drop MyTable --` and ruin database. 
In my solution, however, `sql` is a *local varaibale* which can't be changed by user; `ReadSqlRecords` is a `private` method 
(and thus can't be erroneously call from outside). You are quite right, we shouldn't allow user to run arbitrary queries like `...ReadSqlRecords(Edit1.Text)...`
but this is a different warning.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    // Get the object from the table (in this case I give an example to get the first row. You can use Where for the condition)
    var row = context.MyTable.FirstOrDefault();

    // Get the field value with reflection
    response = row.GetType().GetProperty(name).GetValue(row, null).ToString();
}
```

Comment: `Select(x => x.fieldName)` does the same thing as `select I.fieldName` would do.

Comment: This will simply return a collection of strings, where each string will be the name of the field.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I changed the answer